# How to find duration of video recorded with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

If we use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, we have `recordedDuration` property on it that gives the length of the video recorded.

However I couldn't find anything similar for video recorded using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` then in your delegate callback

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

you can calculate the recorded duration by noting the presentation time stamps of the first and last `sampleBuffer`s that you record:

```
CMTime start = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBufferFirst);
CMTime end = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBufferLast);

CMTime recordedDuration = CMTimeSubtract(end, start);
```